# dynamically append an list item to a list view with both a text value and an id

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How do you dynamically append an list item to a list view with both a text value and an id ?

attempted the following :
$('#selectedEmployees').append(' + $(this).text() + '').listview('refresh');

Answer (score 1):

Using the jQuery `attr()` method, like most jQuery methods it is chainable which means you can call one after another on the same element.

```
$(this).attr('id', 'myId').text('test');
```

Your code might look something like this

```
$('#selectedEmployees').append( $(this).attr('id','myId').text('test') ).listview('refresh');
```